# removing unwanted quotes from string with python

Tags: python, folium

im querying my mysql database for user coordinates and feeding the output to a function.
i intend to get map view from this user_location.

here is part of the code:

```
def map_view():
    u = conn.execute("select provider_point from providers where username = %s"% "'"+session["current_user"]+"'")
user = u.fetchone() 

print(user)
#gives ('-1.1477195,37.0630088',)
#converting to []  
start_coords = "["+(', '.join(user))+"]".replace("'","")
print(start_coords)
#gives which is what i want
[-1.1477195,37.0630088]
```

this gives me what i want but when i pass it to folium maps it recieves it as    '[-1.1477195,37.0630088]'
how do i get rid of the quotes(') ?

Comment: please fix your indentation, we can't tell where the function definition ends (if it does). Also please add the part where you pass it to folium, I don't see that anywehre.

Comment: can you please give me the type of user? is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

As I can infer from the provided snippet, `start_coords` is of string type and undoubtedly, this is what you're getting. As it is a list of string, you can convert it to float before passing. Try

```
start_coords = start_coords.replace('[', '')
start_coords = start_coords.replace(']', '')
lis = start_coords.split(',')
lis = [float(i) for i in lis]
```

This outputs

```
[-1.1477195, 37.0630088]
```

where `type(lis[0])` is float. So, `lis` is a list of float. Now, lis can be passed to folium maps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `user` is a tuple. You can pull out the first (and, by the looks of the example, only) item from the tuple with `user[0]` or simply loop over it.

```
for item in user:
    print("[{}]".format(item))
```

The parentheses and the quotes are not part of the value, it's how Python formats a `tuple` when you attempt to `print` it, just like it supplies `[`...`]` around a list, `{` and `:` and `,` and `}` to disambiguate a `dict`, etc.

```
>>> example = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(example)
[1, 2, 3]
```

but `[` is not part of the first value:

```
>>> print(example[0])
1
```